# How do I get the content of the div on a key press so that it also includes the text which was entered on that keypress?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, contenteditable, onkeypress

I have a contenteditable div and the user can enter or modify the text in it.I want to display the text in another div 
html code:

```
    <div contenteditable="true" id ="a1">
    </div>
    <div id="a2">
    </div>
```

the javascript code:

```
    var x=document.getElementById("a1");
    x.onkeypress=function(){
    var z= document.getElementById("a2");
    z.innerHTML=x.innerHTML;

    };
```

but it displays the content with one letter less than the actual data i have in the `"a1"` div or one letter more If I press the back-space key.I want to synchronize the content in both divs i.e. the modified text after this key press event.How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `onkeyup` event instead of `onkeypress` . It's more realtime since it fires before keypress :)

```
var x=document.getElementById("a1");
x.onkeyup=function()
{
  var z= document.getElementById("a2");
  z.innerHTML=x.innerHTML;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the onkeyup event instead. It kicks in when the key has been released, and the new key has been registered.
Another problem with onkeypress is that it only works for printable characters, so it won't fire for backspace

Answer (score 1):

try changing the `x.onkeypress` for `x.onkeyup`, since the action is taking place when you press the key, before the system has the key input

```
var x=document.getElementById("a1");
//use onkeyup to process the key after the input
x.onkeyup=function(){
    var z= document.getElementById("a2");
    z.innerHTML=x.innerHTML;
};
```

Here's [this link](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/KeyPress-KeyDown-KeyUp-The-Difference-Between-Javascript-Key-Events.aspx) for more reference